# Executing shell script that takes a input through ant

Tags: unix, ant

I have input.sh shell script which asks for user input,it works fine!!. Now i want to call input.sh through ant,i am able to do that but i'm not able to pass the input to the shell script. I have missed anything? Below is the snipped for build.xml and input.sh with execution result.

input.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter the Organization name"
read Orgname
echo "Orgname is : $Orgname"
sed "s/000/$Orgname/g" Final.sql >> ExecuteID.sql
echo "Organization name has been replaced with $Orgname"
```

Result:

```
[root@krog2-rhel5-64 Work]# ./input.sh
enter the Organization name
**yak
Orgname is : yak
Organization name has been replaced with yak**
```

build.xml

```
<project name="Sample" default="automate">
<target name="automate">
<exec executable="/bin/bash">
<arg value="/root/test/Work/input.sh"/>
<arg value="/root/test/Work"/>
</exec>
</project>
```

Result:

```
[root@krog2-rhel5-64 Work]# ant
Buildfile: /root/test/Work/build.xml

automate:
     [exec] enter the Organization name
     [exec] **Orgname is :
     [exec] Organization name has been replaced with**

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Any help in this matter will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176305/ant-exec-task-how-can-i-read-input-from-console-stdin

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing Shell Script through ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268696/executing-shell-script-through-ant)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to pass the `$Orgname` in the `build.xml`.

```
<project name="Sample" default="automate">   
  <target name="automate">
    <exec executable="/bin/bash">
      <arg value="echo 'yak' | /root/test/Work/input.sh"/>
    </exec>   
  </target> 
</project>
```

Comment: input:
     [exec] /bin/bash: echo 'yak' | input.sh: No such file or directory
     [exec] Result: 127
it is not identifying that statement. when is removed "echo 'yak'...its picking the file correctly but when i say  <arg value="echo 'yak' | /root/test/Work/input.sh"/>  it gives above mentioned error